# What is the chance of an event happening a set number of times or more after a number of trials?

Tags: statistics

Assuming every trial is independent from all the others and the probability of a successful run is the same every trial, how can you determine the chance of a successful trial a set number of times or more?

For example, You run 20 independent trials and the chance of a "successful" independent trial each time is 60%. how would you determine the chance of 3 or more"successful" trials?

Comment: Do these three successful trials have to happen in a row?

Comment: No. I'm sorry I wasn't more specific. The successful trials do not have to occur in any particular order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the probability of success on any trial is $p$, then the probability of **exactly** $k$ successes in $n$ trials is
$$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$
For details, look for the [Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) on Wikipedia.

So to calculate the probability of $3$ or more successes in your example, let $p=0.60$ and $n=20$. Then calculate the probabilities that  $k=3$, $k=4$, and so on up to $k=20$ using the above formula, and add up.

A lot of work!  It is much easier in this case to find the probability of $2$ or fewer successes by using the above formula, and subtracting the answer from $1$. So, with $p=0.60$, the probability of $3$ or more successes is
$$1-\left(\binom{20}{0}p^0(1-p)^{20}+\binom{20}{1}p(1-p)^{19}+\binom{20}{2}p^2(1-p)^{18}    \right).$$

For the calculations, note that $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. In particular, $\binom{20}{0}=1$, $\binom{20}{1}=20$ and $\binom{20}{2}=\frac{(20)(19)}{2!}=190$.