# How to calculate the chance that element is picked from set of nine five times or more

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

I have a set of 9 different elements. How do I calculate the chance that when I pick one element out of the set 20 times, I have the same one 5 times or more?

I thought about using the following formula: if the probability of success on any trial is $p$, then the probability of **exactly** $k$ successes in $n$ trials is
$$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$ ([Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178837/what-is-the-chance-of-an-event-happening-a-set-number-of-times-or-more-after-a-n#178850))

Then we have $p$ equal to $1/9$, $n$ equal to $20$ and $k$ equal to $5$ till $20$ and add up the values. We multiply this by $\binom{20}{4}$ so we take into account that there are $\binom{20}{4}$ ways to pick 4 elements out of 20.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite, I'm not sure where you got $\binom{20}{4}$ from.
The probability that you get exactly $5$ successes out of $20$ is
$$\binom{20}{5}\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^5\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^{15}.$$

However, you are interested in $5$ or more, and since the events are mutually exclusive, then the probability of interest is the sum of the probabilities of getting 5, or, 6, or 7,... or 20 successes;
$$\sum_{k=5}^{20}\binom{20}{k}\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^k\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^{20-k}.$$

This is equivalent to 
$$1-P(4\text{ or fewer successes}) = 1-\sum_{k=0}^4\binom{20}{k}\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^k\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^{20-k}.$$

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a good program to get the answer? [I tried Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?lk=3&i=1+-+sum+binomial%2820,k%29*%28binomial%281,9%29%29^k*%28binomial%288,9%29%29^%2820-k%29,+k%3D0+to+4), but I don't think the answer it gives (1) is correct.

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers I fixed it. [Click here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?lk=3&i=1+-+sum+binomial%2820,k%29*%281%2F9%29^k*%288%2F9%29^%2820-k%29,+k%3D0+to+4). It was because you wrote `binomial(1,9)` instead of `(1/9)`. Same thing with `(8/9)`. I use R [https://www.r-project.org/about.html](https://www.r-project.org/about.html), but most programs/language can do this, even WA. :p

Comment: Ohhh oops. Thank you. :)

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers No problem. Good luck.